# tensorflow conv2d memory consumption explain?

Tags: memory, tensorflow, convolution, tensorboard

```
output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights, strides = [1,3,3,1], padding = 'VALID')
```

My `input` has shape 200x225x225x1, `weights` is 15x15x1x64. Hence, the `output` has shape 200x71x71x64 since `(225-15)/3 + 1 = 71`

Tensorboard shows that this operation consumes totally 768MB (see pic below). Assuming it takes into account the size of input (38.6MB), weights (0.06MB) and output (246.2MB) the total memory consumption should not exceed 300MB. So where does the rest of the memory consumption come from?

[image: tensorboard]

Comment: You need to post complete (minimal) code: what are you doing with the output, etc.

Comment: @MaxB I thought the memory consumption of a node in a graph is not affected by the operations in other nodes following it? My graph is very complicated (multi-layer network) and this is the first node accepting input from a placeholder. Will try to reproduce the problem with simpler network.

Comment: If you are calculating the gradient, perhaps that's counted in the node memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not able to reproduce your graph and values based on information provided, it's possible that you're seeing additional memory usage due to intermediary values materialized during the computation of Conv2D. It's also possible that the instrumentation is incorrect. (e.g. reshape operations that do not result in a copy of Tensor memory end up duplicating the "memory usage" in the TF Node Stats instrumentation.) Without a reproducible test case, it's hard to say more. If you do feel like this is a bug in TensorFlow, please do raise an issue on Github!