# Design tricks for memory efficient TensorFlow NN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run a simple convolutional neural network with TensorFlow on CPU, using Python/Numpy to load data from disk and prepare it. The Python/Numpy part consumes very little memory, as expected since I'm loading just 32 1MB images.

However, with running `sess.run(AdamOptimizer)` memory usage peaks astronomically, as can be seen in below [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) output, showing 4 training cycles and one test cycle.
[image: TensorFlow memory usage, 4 training cycles one test cycle, from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler]

The 12GB peak limits the size of my batches, the number of concurrently training networks or the size of my layers. I believe this peak has to do with the data transfer from Python to TF or with the forward activation because it exists equivalently in the `sess.run(accuracy)` statement.

Did I maybe poorly design the CNN graph? Can someone point to design rules I should keep in mind, specifically for memory? Is it possible to smear this out in time? - it would be an improvement if the 12GB peak took twice as long and was half as high. And finally is there a way to signal the peak start and end time, such that I can manage multiple networks to train interlaced? (note the narrow 2 second peak occurs within a single  `sess.run()` statement that takes about 20 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd gladly transfer the answer tick if someone else has anything to add. Just wanted to share what I have found.

It appears that `tf.nn.conv2d` is especially memory hungry, maybe it makes total sense somehow but to me it is way more than expected. The following simple program uses 5.5GB where I wouldn't expect more than a few 100 MB:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 4])
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([f, f, 4, 8], stddev=0.1))
outp = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

outp_v = sess.run(outp,
       feed_dict={x:np.ones(32*256*256*4).reshape(32,256,256,4)})
```

As found with memory profiler:
[image: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler/0.47 output.]
For this output I used the fairly large number `f = 16`, but I found the memory usage to be independent of it. Except that at small enough `f` the computation is so fast that it drops below the time resolution of the memory profile utility and only a sharp peak (with no plateau) remains at an arbitrary height.

Others have found similar memory usage:
[tensorflow conv2d memory consumption explain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527125/tensorflow-conv2d-memory-consumption-explain)

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of optimizer is the reason for the 4 times memory spike.  Adam uses 8 bits per convolution weight. I plan to use a different optimizer like AdaFactorOptimizer as suggested by google

Reference:
Sub headings: Large number of model weights
https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting